# How can update values in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

how to get new array newSelect using map ,forEach

```
const selects = [false, true, true, true, false];
    const oldSelects = [
      { select: true, name: 'AA' },
      { select: true, name: 'AA' },
      { select: true, name: 'AA' },
      { select: true, name: 'AA' },
      { select: true, name: 'AA' },
    ];
    const newSelect = [
      { select: false, name: 'AA' },
      { select: true, name: 'AA' },
      { select: true, name: 'AA' },
      { select: true, name: 'AA' },
      { select: false, name: 'AA' },
    ];
```

**oldSelects[0].select === selects[0]**

Comment: Hello! Can you be more clear? What is the expected result? follow this link instruction please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have tagged this question with [tag:reactjs] -- is this correct?  If so, you should include some of the React context because if this is an item stored in state you may need to handle it differently than you would in a vanilla JS context...

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can map the old array to a new one.

```js
const selects = [false, true, true, true, false];
const oldSelects = [{
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
];

const newSelect = oldSelects.map((object, index) => {
  object['select'] = selects[index]
  return object;
})

console.log(newSelect)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Inder answer is great, but a map looks more clean imo:

```js
const selects = [false, true, true, true, false];
const oldSelects = [{
    select: true,
    name: "AA"
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: "AA"
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: "AA"
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: "AA"
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: "AA"
  }
];
const newSelect = oldSelects.map((el, i) => ({
  select: selects[i],
  name: el.name
}));

console.log(newSelect);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using forEach

```js
const selects = [false, true, true, true, false];
const oldSelects = [{
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
];

const newSelects = []

oldSelects.forEach((selectItem, index) => newSelects.push({...selectItem, select: selects[index]}))
console.log(newSelects)
```

## Using map

```js
const selects = [false, true, true, true, false];
const oldSelects = [{
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
  {
    select: true,
    name: 'AA'
  },
];
const newSelects = oldSelects.map((selectItem, index) => ({...selectItem, select: selects[index]}))

console.log(newSelects)
```